# Auto update browser when HTML is changed

Tags: html, google-chrome, dreamweaver, visual-web-developer

I'm building a website in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web and Dreamweaver CS6 and neither of the inbuilt browsers are decent enough, is there a way to view saved changes instantly on the browser without manually refreshing (currently I use an auto-refresher and I don't like it because the page flashes and you can't scroll because it jumps to the top).

Is there a plugin which I can use or an external program?

Ideally I would like Chrome or Opera and I did make something which does what I need but uses IE - so no good in a web design view and it was a bit clunky.

(I'm not sure where else I should have asked this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chrome plugin you need is [Tincr](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tincr/lfjbhpnjiajjgnjganiaggebdhhpnbih)

> Tincr does two things.
>
> **Allows you to easily save changes you make in Chrome Developer Tools**. For example, you may find yourself in the devtools’ Element inspector
> panel experimenting with css changes. Normally, you would then have to
> copy and paste your changes to your file or lose your changes when you
> reload the page or navigate elsewhere. You can configure Tincr to
> automatically save these changes to the right file.
>
> **Automatically reload changes made from your Editor or IDE**. You can configure Tincr
> to watch for changes to files and then reload the corresponding url.
> It can either do a full refresh of the page or reload the url in
> place. Often referred to as live reload or auto refresh.

The docs are available here http://tin.cr/docs.html

Comment: I came across this before but it no longer works and no longer supported, it also uses an API which is being phased out - thanks for the post though

Answer (score 0):

if you are using dw cs6, set the default browser to chrome. next open the split view  and make the design panel live( right ) edit the code of the page or style sheet or whatever in the  editor (Left)
 then click the design panel and it will show your changes right away
if your adding new resources to the file folders hit the refresh button to include

Answer (score -1):

In Dreamweaver, File -> Preview in Browser -> Edit Browser List  Change default to Chrome F12

Comment: The browser doesn't refresh when an edit is saved - that's my problem